# How to put annotations on a new line with JavaParser?

Tags: java, annotations, javaparser

I want to add an annotation to a field with javaparser.

```
public static String annotate() {
    String classString = new StringJoiner("\n")
            .add("class A {")
            .add("")
            .add("  @ExistingAnnotation")
            .add("  private int i;")
            .add("")
            .add("}")
            .toString();

    CompilationUnit cu = StaticJavaParser.parse(classString);
    LexicalPreservingPrinter.setup(cu);

    cu.findFirst(FieldDeclaration.class).get()
            .addAnnotation("Annotation")
            .addAnnotation(Nonnull.class)
            .addMarkerAnnotation("MarkerAnnotation");

    return LexicalPreservingPrinter.print(cu);
}
```

But contrary to what I expect the added annotation is not put on its own line but appended to the existing annotation on the same line

```
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;

class A {

  @ExistingAnnotation @Annotation() @Nonnull() @MarkerAnnotation
  private int i;

}
```

Instead I want

```
  @ExistingAnnotation
  @Annotation()
  @Nonnull()
  @MarkerAnnotation
  private int i;
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try to print with:

```
new DefaultPrettyPrinter().print(cu);
```

Comment: LexicalPreservingPrinter has no way of knowing how to print the new annotations, but the pretty printer prints with its own formatting rules.

    cu.toString() uses pretty printer