# Javaparser: how to annotate existing classes?

Tags: java, class, annotations, javaparser

I am trying to annotate a class with a custom annotation. I have a simple class (Foo) and a ClassVisitor, which add the annotation to an existing class.

```
public class Foo{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SourceRoot sourceRoot = new SourceRoot(Path.of(".\"));
        CompilationUnit cu = sourceRoot.parse("", "MyFile.java);
        ClassVisitor cv = new ClassVisitor();
        cu.accept(cv, null);
    }
}

class ClassVisitor extends VoidVisitorAdapter<Void> {

    private final String MY_ANNOTATION = "@myAnnotation";
    
    @Override
    public void visit(ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration cid, Void arg) {
        super.visit(cid, arg);
        boolean isAnnotated = false;
        for (Node node : cid.getAnnotations()){
            if (MY_ANNOTATION == node.toString()) {
                isAnnotated = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isAnnotated == false) {
            cid.addAnnotation(MY_ANNOTATION); // error happens here
        }
    }
}
```

When the code is executed I get the error below:

> Exception in thread "main"
> com.github.javaparser.ParseProblemException: Encountered unexpected
> token: "@" "@"
> at line 1, column 1.
>
> Was expecting one of:
>
> ```
> "enum"
> "exports"
> "module"
> "open"
> "opens"
> "provides"
> "record"
> "requires"
> "strictfp"
> "to"
> "transitive"
> "uses"
> "with"
> "yield"
> <IDENTIFIER>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Omit the `@`, just use the annotation name

```
private final String MY_ANNOTATION = "myAnnotation";
```

See: [How to put annotations on a new line with JavaParser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66698723/how-to-put-annotations-on-a-new-line-with-javaparser)